# Union-Type turns into Intersection-Type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

### Problem

I want to create a factory that delivers different functions depending on the given parameters.
This can be solved with conditional types.

```
type DispatchConditional<TPayload> = TPayload extends undefined
  ? () => void
  : (payload: TPayload) => void;
```

The type `DispatchCondition` can be instrumented by an interface.

```
interface ActionDispatcher<TPayload> {
  dispatch: DispatchConditional<TPayload>;
}
```

If I build a factory based on the definitions above, it will break if a `Union-Type` is used.
Somehow the union-type defined by `payloadUnion()` becomes an `Intersection-Type`.

[image]

### Question

What adjustments do I have to make to produce a type definition for the method `dispatch` that supports union-types?

### Playground

- [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=14&pln=7&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwM4QIYgMYAsDCB7AOwBMEQFDUAbAHgBUAFVMSvVIgPhgF4YGmW2MKAA8QUYkhgBXYlABmCAlCLAYMAPwwAFAEpunAG54EKtQC5taZqyIW+1tnq6HjRANzBgisQCc5qDFgAQQwyQkQUdGwoHzpGBw4YAG9VGBJIzCwLCLRM-GJScgIqOP4bdg8AX09waBgQbhgQsIIcqKwY6gIpAFsAIxiYAB8Ybv6YgG0AXXZPORlQoph-DDp2LSsBInU7HQtmorbMztpOFLUfKBApHwJkyphUSVQCMGBq4HmCRcIYTZsAKoEIq6CxjAY+YajXoQ6bJGCXa63GAABhglQ8wAwhCQDRAAEZGisNmU2ECQTodJiCQA6dK5bC6IA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DispatchConditional` is a [distributed conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). This means that `DispatchConditional<number | number[]>`  is equivalent to `DispatchConditional<number> | DispatchConditional<number[]>` which in turn will be a union of functions. And a union of functions is only callable with an intersection of the parameter type (since we don't know which function we actually get at runtime, we have to provide parameters that work with BOTH function signatures, resulting in the intersection)

The simple solution is to disable the distributive behavior, by wrapping the type parameter in a tuple type ( distribution only happens over naked type parameters):

```
type DispatchConditional<TPayload> = [TPayload] extends [undefined]
  ? () => void
  : (payload: TPayload) => void;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=21&ssc=14&pln=21&pc=15#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwM4QIYgMYAsDCB7AOwBMEQFDUAbAHgBUAFVMSvVIgPhgF4YBtBpizYBdGFAAeIKMSR8ArsSgAzBAShFhwGDAD8MABQBKbpwBueBES0wAXAbTNWROwMdtjXMxaIBuYMFUpACclVAxYAEEMMkJEFHRsKCC6RjcOGABvaxJ4zCw7OLQ8-GJScgIqFMEndj8AX39waBgQbhgomIJChKwk6gI5AFsAIySYAB8YAZGk3mF2fyUFaPKYUIw6dn0HISIdF0M7DvLuvL7aTiztIKgQOSCCTLqYVFlUAjBgBuAlghXCGA7JwAVQI5SMdmmoyCEymQ2hc0yMBudweMAADDA6n5gBhCEhWiAAIxtdbbapsUHgwyGHHEgB0OSK2H06NpoCJjOQzKw+l46OEtKAA)

Comment: Wow, what a quick answer. Thank you so much!