# Why is Typescript union converted to intersection in function parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function that adds a new entry to a database.

There are two tables: `Dog` and `Cat`, and the `addPet` function accepts a `type` (`dog` or `cat`) and the `details` (an object conforming to the corresponding DogInfo or CatInfo interface):

```
interface DogInfo {
  canine: boolean
  name: string
}

interface CatInfo {
  feline: boolean
  name: string
}

const pets = new PetDb()

const addPet = (
  type: 'dog' | 'cat', 
  info: DogInfo | CatInfo
) => { 
  return pets[type].add(info)
}
```

So for example:

```
addPet('cat', {feline: true, name: 'lolcat'})
```

However Typescript complains because it has created an intersection based on the union:

[image]

It says "property 'feline' is missing in type 'DogInfo' but required in type 'CatInfo'."

The explanation seems to be that *"since we don't know which function we actually get at runtime, we have to provide parameters that work with BOTH function signatures, resulting in the intersection"* from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61598134/1058302).

Is this the same issue as in the other question? I'm not sure, and is there a simple way to address this? It seems like a common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do:

[Here is a link to a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBCBhA9iEBTYAXAlsgdgLLLADWAPACoB80A3gLABQ0r0YAJhwBQ5boBbAFzRKASnrM206MAIRU6AHQhkAc24ADAJL8B7Lug7QsyOPE0AaaH0FiA3FLYBfZq6bMc%20fgCcAZmDA6NAACuhYkixs%20GAC6CIQWD5eao5M7p7e6P6BwbDq2vh%20ZugAHvz4HDBhEYxRwGD4XvHQAEbIio1uzJm%20AUHQiGBYhcXQZRVVoeGRrH7oIM0i7Z343R5MXn250No1CLNsDVgiCChomLgExGTkNdRp0hzqp0ioGNh4RCQU92kZTFAkGq4QOOAEAAcMHFvDA9qD4IdWMdoABeaD4dAAd3M5w%20V2%20tyGIyKyGo3AcTlYzzUaIx2Nx70uXxuFHyalGZIp-x6TAA9HzmFgAJ4Q4IAQS4xMKEIArhF0XVpCKxSIAETHNWPNheYoiaWknkbFUSrjsmXyulKtgm9U0rVUmyk04FQ3rZhAqDTLAAZWyADccANrcj5ElZdhkD5uBDkv7hsEfOhOAQQMLoGKsAgRPCs-AJHR3NJOBwanSY%20ERJKOAa5READ7Qavm-B1iSo2ghmRYAAWOAgSkzCAA2pmlCaALpKEsVrBKXXISlRVjuAEC-iJGxYXlyfCboeI9GYnH7eDcndhjPhP0%20QMDI8Mmo3u-oWcIJfMTPPoPKEs1bh0CYootBqwxqtYC4iIB8yLJiIjhug1gxHE6qUMgAhqiuzhLl%20AY-tOXD-oBtrQGq9oQc69CyI0SwmD4sqIRisQgQA0nwIqDGB0DONxDhAA)

```js
// 1. Have a base interface for pets
interface Pet {
    name: string;
}
interface DogInfo extends Pet {
  canine: boolean
}
interface CatInfo extends Pet {
  feline: boolean
}

//2 Abstract the DB through an interface
interface IPetDB {
    cat: DBCollectionMock<Pet>;
    dog: DBCollectionMock<Pet>;
}

//3 Use the Interface


//3.1 through a class
class PetService {
    constructor(private readonly petDB: IPetDB) {}
    addPet = (pet: AddCatInput | AddDogInput) => {
        this.petDB[pet.type].add(pet.info);
    }
}

// 3.2 or by providing the db dependency to the method

const addPet = (pet: AddCatInput | AddDogInput, petDB: IPetDB) => {
        petDB[pet.type].add(pet.info);
}
```

[Here is a link to a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBCBhA9iEBTYAXAlsgdgLLLADWAPACoB80A3gLABQ0r0YAJhwBQ5boBbAFzRKASnrM206MAIRU6AHQhkAc24ADAJL8B7Lug7QsyOPE0AaaH0FiA3FLYBfZq6bMc%20fgCcAZmDA6NAACuhYkixs%20GAC6CIQWD5eao5M7p7e6P6BwbDq2vh%20ZugAHvz4HDBhEYxRwGD4XvHQAEbIio1uzJm%20AUHQiGBYhcXQZRVVoeGRrH7oIM0i7Z343R5MXn250No1CLNsDVgiCChomLgExGTkNdRp0hzqp0ioGNh4RCQU92kZTFAkGq4QOOAEAAcMHFvDA9qD4IdWMdoABeaD4dAAd3M5w%20V2%20tyGIyKyGo3AcTlYzzUaIx2Nx70uXxuFHyalGZIp-x6TAA9HzmFgAJ4Q4IAQS4xMKEIArhF0XVpCKxSIAETHNWPNheYoiaWknkbFUSrjsmXyulKtgm9U0rVUmyk04FQ3rZhAqDTLAAZWyADccANrcj5ElZdhkD5uBDkv7hsEfOhOAQQMLoGKsAgRPCs-AJHR3NJOBwanSY%20ERJKOAa5READ7Qavm-B1iSo2ghmRYAAWOAgSkzCAA2pmlCaALpKEsVrBKXXISlRVjuAEC-iJGxYXlyfCboeI9GYnH7eDcndhjPhP0%20QMDI8Mmo3u-oWcIJfMTPPoPKEs1bh0CYootBqwxqtYC4iIB8yLJiIjhug1gxHE6qUMgAhqiuzhLl%20AY-tOXD-oBtrQGq9oQc69CyI0SwmD4sqIRisQgQA0nwIqDGB0DONxDhAA)